# A SparesMissing event had been detected on md device /dev/md0

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid

I'm getting the following mail every day on a server:

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on <host>

A SparesMissing event had been detected on md device /dev/md0.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      731592000 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

The output from `cat /proc/mdstat` looks fine though, so it's not obvious what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cause was an erroneous `spares=1` option in the `mdadm.conf`:

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=621d5f15:cce75825:60273c48:78a7dac7
   spares=1
```

I'm not sure how this ended up there, but I suppose it happened when a device failed and was replaced.

Removing the `spares=1` option or just recreating the `mdadm.conf` from scratch fixes the problem:

```
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Comment: Strangely enough, this was my exact situation. There was a `spares=1` with unknown origins. This raid array (and the whole system) was set up recently, though, so it can't have gotten in there when "replacing a disk". Still, glad to see a solution even if it does still leave some questions

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I got the message, however I have a spare disk.
The answer above puzzled me a little.
The resolution appeared to be simple.

There was `spares=2` in my `mdadm.conf`.
The odd thing is - I haven't configured that.
It must have been done by some installation script.
I have two RAIDs with one spare each.
The first one got properly "spares=1" and the second one `spares=2`.

Comment: Maybe `mdadm --create` has an off-by-one class bug.
PS: was the incorrectly configured one created as RAID5?